# Is there a day ticket I can buy for a day trip from Kolding to Billund?

Tags: tickets, buses, denmark, day-trips

I'm going to visit Lego House in Billund, though my hotel is in Kolding since it is cheaper. I plan to take the bus 166.

A one-way ticket seems to cost 72 dkk though it seems that there is also currently this ticket called "Trekantfest M" available at 75 dkk for a [local art festival](https://www.trekantfest.dk/). Unfortunately the description is in Danish, so I'm not sure if this will indeed allow me to take bus 166 twice in the same day, i.e. whether the "lokal/regionalbusser" includes the bus 166.

The following is the description:

[image: Description]

Should I buy this ticket? Is there any other day ticket that might be the most economic for me?

Comment: It just says valid for a whole day, so I guess you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a native Dane, I would definitely consider "by-, lokal- og regionalbusser" to include that route. The geographical area matches too, and it explicitly says it is valid all day, so I'd say you're good to go with that ticket.

The only strange point is that I cannot find any mention of the special ticket you show on *either* the festival's or the transit agency's websites ...

Comment: Yes I can only see it in the Sydtrafik mobile app

Comment: I was just able to take the bus with this ticket.